# Renaming Gradle Uploaded Artifacts

Tags: java, maven, gradle, build.gradle, artifactory

I’m trying to upload my Project’s Gradle artifacts to JFROG-Artifactory using the below gradle-cli command.
“build artifactoryPublish”

Please find the build.gradle i have used

```
    apply plugin: 'war'
war.archiveName "Sample.war"

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://abcd-artifactory.com:443/artifactory/maven-plugins-release-virtual'
            credentials {
                username = "${artifactory_user}"
                password = "${artifactory_password}"
            }
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        //Check for the latest version here: http://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.jfrog.artifactory
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.15.1"
    }
    //configurations {
    //       warLib {
    //            transitive=false
    //        }
    //}
}


apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

//artifacts {
//  archives file("Sample.war")
//}

//war {
//        classpath configurations.warLib
//}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.web
            groupId = 'ABCD'
            artifactId = 'DEV'
            version = "1.0"
            //artifact(file('build/libs/Sample.war'))
        }
    }
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"   //The base Artifactory URL if not overridden by the publisher/resolver
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'team-abcd'
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true
        }
        defaults {
            publications('mavenJava')
            //publishConfigs('archives') 
            publishArtifacts = true
            properties = ['qa.level': 'basic', 'dev.team' : 'core']
            publishBuildInfo = false
            publishPom = false
        }
        resolve {
            repository {
                repoKey = 'maven-libs-release-virtual'
                username = "${artifactory_user}"
                password = "${artifactory_password}"
                maven = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After running “gradle build artifactoryPublish”, i can see that the war file is being sent to the Artifactory
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9aHF.png)

I have a couple of queries

1. Is there a way the name of war file appearing in Artifactory can be modified (by modifying build.gradle) during the gradle tasks? if yes, how?
   It’s currently showing “DEV-1.0.war” , i would like to see any custom name ex-- WELCOME.war
2. Why is the pom file being published even though i have set “publishPom=false” in the defaults section
3. I’m using war plugin to set Custom name of War file, how can i upload that Sample.war to Artifactory

Comment: If you write to a Maven repository, you need to publish a POM as well.

Comment: Thank you @JFabianMeier, could you also help me with my Queries 1 and 3.